# Unequally spaced subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I got 3 pairs of images that I would like to have paired together (See first figure, which is created by using a simple plt.subplots(161), with axes turned off for the even numbered subplots.)

Since the image contains 3 pairs of images, I would like each pair to be togetherm thus with smaller spacing. (See 2nd figure, which I edited with photoshop).

What I have:
[image]
What I want it to be:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps use subfigures https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subfigures.html

Comment: It would help to see your code.